# See what Vim `:!` executes

Tags: shell, escape, filter

Between

- `:%!`
- `exe "!..."`
- `exe "!bash -c" shellescape(...)`

I'm getting quite confused as to what exactly Vim invokes. And I suspect at some point it invokes `bash -c bash ...`. Is there a way to see exactly what shell command is being called out? Does Vim ever invoke directly the command after `!`, or does it always wrap the command in `bash -c ...`?

I'm really trying to invoke a shell command, stored in `g:cmd`, which has a `%` in it, with as little overhead as possible (i.e., no `bash -c bash`). It's supposed to act as a filter on the visual selection. But

```
exe "'<,'>!" g:cmd  # Substitutes '%'
exe "'<,'>! bash -c" shellescape( g:cmd, 1 )  # Maybe wraps 2x bash around
exe "'<,'>!" shellescape( g:cmd, 1/0 )  # Bash calls g:cmd as executable -> error
```

Comment: You know you can write a wrapper and set `'shell'` to be that. It can be a script that does whatever you want...prints the parameters passed to it, for instance.

Comment: Aha, that's the answer to the debugging question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `!` or `:!` Vim builds the invoking command based on whatever is specified in the various `'shell...'` settings (i.e. `'shell'`, `'shellcmdflag'`, `'shellquote'`, to name three). On Unix systems the defaults for the first two are usually the default shell (`$SHELL`) and `-c` so if I'm using Bash and I do `:!foo bar` the call Vim makes will look like:

```
/bin/bash -c "foo bar"
```

So, to answer your question: No, Vim never directly calls the command after `!`.

---

The above answers the one concrete question I saw in the question's text but as we sussed out in the comments there was also a question about how to debug things in this situation. For the benefit of other readers I'll repeat here what I suggested:

A good way to get insight into what exactly gets passed by Vim to the `'shell'` program is to write your own "shell". By which I mean write a wrapper script which contains whatever you want. The most obvious thing to do is just have it print all the params/args received. Now set `'shell'` to point to that instead of `/bin/bash` or whatever it's currently pointing to, make a `:!` call and start debugging.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way to see exactly what shell command is being called out?

To see what exactly is run,

```
:echo getpid()
```

will show vim's PID, e.g. `1234`, with which you can then in another terminal run:

```
sudo strace -fe trace=execve -p 1234
```

then in vim you can use any shell-invoking command like:

```
:!echo foo
```

and in the terminal running `strace` see something like:

```
[pid 1737876] execve("/usr/bin/zsh", ["zsh", "-c", "echo foo"], 0x561845a10070 /* 48 vars */) = 0
```

`zsh -c` is used because I have `:set shell=zsh`, but that's exactly what's being run. You can use this to see how vim processes characters like `%`, `#`, `\`, or `|`.

For example,

```
:!echo \%\|
```

results in

```
[pid 1747484] execve("/usr/bin/zsh", ["zsh", "-c", "echo %\\|"], 0x561845a10070 /* 48 vars */) = 0
```

`strace` might show much more output than you might be interested in. You can use `grep` to filter what you want, but note that the output is through stderr instead of stdout, so instead of a simple `|`, you should use something like `|&`. e.g.

```
sudo strace -fe trace=execve -p 1234 |& grep echo
```

This works for stuff beyond `vim`.

Comment: A bit overkill, but it's a nice one! I believe you typically don't need `sudo` for this, but that actually might depend on some settings in `/proc` and might depend on which O.S. you're in... Would you try it without `sudo` to see if it still works as expected?

Comment: @filbranden You don't need `sudo` when having `strace` start a new process, but you do need it to attach to an existing one. I get `strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, 1791897): Operation not permitted`.

Comment: There's also `ltrace -fp`, though I'm not getting anything useful in a quick test

Comment: `strace` has `-o`, which could probably be made a fifo if necessary. Or I'm sure it's possible to attach `gdb`. But we're getting really overkill

Comment: @usretc Yes, there's different ways to avoid using `sudo`, but I figured that the process you're trying to debug could include important context that's not simple to replicate in a new `vim` instance. That's why being able to attach to a pre-existing process rather than invoking a new one seemed more valuable from a debugging perspective. I didn't think people would have many qualms of running `strace` with root privileges.

Comment: @usretc That said, I don't know if `ltrace -fp` wouldn't require `sudo` since I've never gotten `ltrace` to work on Archlinux for some reason. However, I'm sure `gdb` does require root to be able to attach to a pre-existing process. If launching a new `vim` process isn't an issue, `strace -o` is probably the simplest option. One could use a fifo as you said, but one can also use a regular file and use `tail -F` in another terminal.

Comment: @JoL some notes -- of course from a debugging POV one wants to attach to an existing PID. I've never thought about avoiding `sudo`, it's not that easy these days. FWIW I haven't been able to get `ltrace` working... for a while now... on Ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

An easy check is `:!foo` that (probably) will print something like `bash: line 1: foo: command not found`. Also see `:h job_start()` (or `:h jobstart()` for Neovim) and so on.

To summarize:

- `:!` always uses `&shell` (as well as `&shellcmdflag`, `&shellquote`, `&shellxqoute` and so on);
- `:h system()` and `:h systemlist()` use `&shell` in Vim; in Neovim it depends on the first parameter (String = shell, List = direct);
- `:h job_start()` executes directly (Vim specific)
- `:h jobstart()` works like `system()`, i.e. String = shell, List = direct (Neovim specific)
- `:h :term` in Vim executes command directly (`&shell` is the default);
- `:h :term` in Neovim uses `&shell` (so `:term sh` results in two shells running one inside another).