# Using the execute shell command (:!) on Windows and MSYS2

Tags: neovim, terminal, microsoft-windows, shell, cygwin

I'm new to neovim (and vim in general), and I'm trying to use it on Windows with MSYS2. I noticed they have a package for vim, but not for neovim.
I used the neovim installed through chocolatey instead, but I couldn't get the :!{cmd}  command to work. It returns "/usr/bin/bash: /s: No such file or directory". Neovim seems to work normally otherwise, including the :terminal command. Is there a way to get around this problem without changing the shell to cmd/powershell?

Comment: Start with `:h 'shell'`. Set that to the location of MSYS2's bash.exe

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I believe the shell was already correctly set, as running :set shell would print out the correct path to bash.exe, and setting it in init.vim did not make any difference.

Comment: Maybe check `shellcmdflag`? Not sure why it would include `/s` though. I can't find anything relevant in the help matching `\/s\>`

Comment: The last paragraph of this answer https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31136/11054 describes a method for debugging how Vim is invoking the shell. It might shine a light on what is happening including what that `/s` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments by B layer and Ben Knoble were both helpful in finding the answer.

Vim correctly set the shell based on the $SHELL variable, but did not set `shellcmdflag` appropriately, and that was what the `/s` was, the default `shellcmdflag` for cmd.exe, as stated in the `:help 'shell'` file.

Setting it to `-c` in my init.vim seems to have solved the problem, and a similar solution found in https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/mattn/vim-lsp-settings/234/631950449 seems to indicate that it might be useful to also set the `shellxquote` and `shellslash` variables. Unlike him, I did not set my PATH or the shell variable itself as I ran neovim from within MSYS2.

I added the following to vim.init so I could still use cmd.exe if I were to run nvim externally.

```bash
if $SHELL == "C:/msys64/usr/bin/bash"
    let &shellcmdflag = '-c'
    set shellxquote=(
    set shellslash
endif
```

Comment: "Vim correctly set.." do you mean NeoVim?

Comment: The link is dead, I'm guessing it's basically https://github.com/mattn/vim-lsp-settings/issues/234